# Как с помощью Bootstrap оставить только нижнюю границу элемента input

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Хочу оставить только нижнюю  границу.

Использовал *Bootstrap* класс `.border-bottom`,  но отображается не правильно:

нижняя граница `input` элемента должна быть как в картинке[image: ввод данных],

Если имеются соображения верстки без подчеркивания нижней границы, то скажите.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: покажите свой код

Answer (score 0):

Использовать .border-bottom идеологически неправильно.
Надо переопределять стили для .form-control 
Отмените ненужные borders, нижнюю границу сделайте явно.

Answer (score 0):

как уже написали выше, создаем свой класс, типа:

```
.form-control-s {
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

И переписываем его вместо `.border-bottom`
Должно получится что то типа `<input class="form-control form-control-s" ... />`

Answer (score 0):

Пример

```css
.form-container {
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #555;
}
.form {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}
.form .form-control {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.form .form-control,
.form .form-control:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center form-container">

  <form class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" required> 
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>

</div>
```